# The maps $f_n: \Bbb R^n \to \Bbb R^{\Bbb N}$ induce final topology $\tau$ on $\Bbb R^\infty$. Compare it with the subspace top from $\Bbb R^{\Bbb N} $

Tags: general-topology, infinite-product

> Let $\Bbb R^\infty$ be the set of sequences in $\Bbb R^{\Bbb N}$ for which $x_j \ne 0$ for finitely many $j$. The maps $f_n:\Bbb R^n \to \Bbb R^{\Bbb N}$ where $f_n(x)=(x_1,x_2, \dots x_n,0,0 \dots)$ and $n \in \Bbb N$ induce the final topology $\tau$ on $\Bbb R^{\infty}$. Compare this topology with the subspace topology inherited from $\Bbb R^{\Bbb N}$.

By definition the final topology $\tau$ is the finest topology you can put on $\Bbb R^\infty$ such that $f_n$’s are continuous. Therefore if $\tau’$ is the subspace topology inherited from $\Bbb R^{\Bbb N} $ we have that $$\tau’ \subseteq \tau.$$

I’m stuck with the other inclusion. I think that it’s by definition that $$\tau’=\{\Bbb R^\infty \cap O \mid O \text{ open in } \Bbb R^{\Bbb N}  \}$$ and that $$\tau=\{V \subset \Bbb R^{\Bbb N}   \mid f^{-1}_n(V) \text{ open in } \Bbb R^{n} \}.$$

Now if I’m to show that $\tau \subseteq \tau’$, then picking $O \in \tau$ I have that $$f^{-1}_n(O)=\{x \in \Bbb R^n \mid (x_1,x_2,\dots, x_n,0,0, \dots) \in \Bbb R^{\Bbb N}   \}$$ is open in $\Bbb R^n$. How can I see wheter this set belongs to $\tau’$?

If $U \in \tau’$, then $$U=\Bbb R^\infty \cap V$$ where $V$ is open in $\Bbb R^{\Bbb N}  $. This can be expressed as $$U= \Bbb R^\infty \cap V = \Bbb R^\infty \cap (\Bbb R \times \Bbb R \times \dots\times V_{i_1} \times V_{i_2} \times \dots \times V_{i_m} )$$ for some $m \in \Bbb N$. What can I do know? Am I to look at the preimage $$f^{-1}_n(\Bbb R^\infty \cap (\Bbb R \times \Bbb R \times \dots\times V_{i_1} \times V_{i_2} \times \dots \times V_{i_m} ) )= f^{-1}_n(\Bbb R^\infty) \cap f^{-1}_n(\Bbb R \times \Bbb R \times \dots\times V_{i_1} \times V_{i_2} \times \dots \times V_{i_m}  )?$$

It looks as $$f^{-1}_n(\Bbb R \times \Bbb R \times \dots\times V_{i_1} \times V_{i_2} \times \dots \times V_{i_m}  ) =\{x \in \Bbb R^n \mid (x_1,x_2,\dots, x_n,0,0, \dots) \in \Bbb R \times \Bbb R \times \dots\times V_{i_1} \times V_{i_2} \times \dots \times V_{i_m} \}$$

but I don’t think this helps. Any ideas what to do here?

Comment: You don't get the result you want because they are not the same topologies. For $\tau$, look for box topology :)

Comment: How do you figure out that they are not the same topologies? It’s not obvious from the construction.

Comment: Because I saw that for sets of the form $U=\prod_{n \in \mathbb{N}} U_n$ where $U_n$ are open in $\mathbb{R}$, we have that $f_n^{-1}(U)= U_1 \times \cdots \times U_n$, so $U \in \tau$. Then, we have that box topology is coarser than $\tau$ (I don't know if they are equal), and as box topology is not the same as product topology for the space $\mathbb{R}^\infty$ we have that $\tau$ and $\tau'$ are not the same.

Comment: Wait, forget it. I'm not sure know if box topology and product topology are different in $\mathbb{R}^\infty$, they are different in $\mathbb{R}^\mathbb{N}$, but in your subset I'm not sure know.

Answer (score 3):

My comments where a little bit misleading but indeed we can show that $\tau' \subsetneq \tau$.

Because each $f_n$ is continuous if we consider in $\mathbb{R}^\mathbb{N}$ the product topology, then each $f_n$ is continuous when we consider its range in $\mathbb{R}^\infty$ with the restricted topology $\tau'$.

Then, as you said, the final topology $\tau$ is the finest topology you can put on $\mathbb{R}^\infty$ such that each $f_n$ is continuous, and so we get that $\tau' \subset \tau$.

Now, to prove that this topologies are not equal consider the set
$$V=\mathbb{R}^\infty \cap \prod_{n \in \mathbb{N}} (-1,1)$$
Observe that clearly $V \subset \mathbb{R}^\infty$ and
$$f_n^{-1}(V)=\{(y_1, \cdots, y_n) \in \mathbb{R}^n: -1 <y_i<1, i=1, \cdots, n\} = (-1,1)^n$$
for each $n \in \mathbb{N}$, so we have that $V \in \tau$.

Now, let's see that $V \not \in \tau'$.

Suppose that $V \in \tau'$, then as $x=(1/2,0,0,\cdots) \in V$ there exists a basic open set $U \in \tau'$ such that $x \in U \subset V$.

As $U$ is a basic set for the product topology on $\mathbb{R}^\infty$, we have that
$$U=\mathbb{R}^\infty \cap \prod_{n \in \mathbb{N}} U_n$$
where every $U_n$ is open in $\mathbb{R}$, and there exists an $n_0 \in \mathbb{N} $ such that $U_n = \mathbb{R}$ for every $n \geq n_0$.

Now, as $x \in U$, we have that $1/2 \in U_1$ and $0 \in U_n$ for every $n >1$.

So define $y: \mathbb{N} \longrightarrow \mathbb{R}$ given by

$$y_n= \left\{ \begin{array}{lcc}
             1/2 &   \text{if}  & n=1 \\
             \\ 0 &  \text{if} & 1<n<n_0 \\
             \\ 2 &    \text{if} & n =n_0\\
             \\ 0 & \text{if} & n>n_0
             \end{array}
   \right.$$
and we get that $y \in U$ but $y \not \in V$, so we have the desired contradiction.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I’m curious couldn’t this be shown just by considering the set $U$ which you define and then showing that $$f^{-1}_n(U)$$ is not open in $\Bbb R^n$? This $U$ can be expressed as a finite intersection of the preimage of the projections $\pi_j^{-1}(V)$, where $V$ is an open set in $\Bbb R^n$. So I think you would have something like $$f^{-1}_n(U) = f^{-1}_n(\bigcap_{k \in K} \pi_k^{-1}(V)) \cap f^{-1}_n(\Bbb R^\infty)$$ and if this isn’t open in $\Bbb R^n$, then $U$ cannot be in $\tau’$?

Comment: And this is because if $O \in \tau$, then $O \in \tau’ \iff O = U \cap \Bbb R^\infty$ for $U$ open in $\Bbb R^{\Bbb N}$. But since $O \in \tau $ the preimage of $O$ is open in $\Bbb R^n$ by definition we just need to see if $$f^{-1}(U \cap \Bbb R^\infty )$$ is open in $\Bbb R^n$. I hope I’m being clear.

Comment: We do not get $y\in U$, because $y\not\in\mathbb{R}^{\infty}$. In fact, if $\emptyset\neq U_n\subseteq\mathbb{R}$ are open and $\mathbb{R}^{\infty}\cap\prod_nU_n\neq\emptyset$, we get that $0\in U_n$ for $n\gg0$ and then $\mathbb{R}^{\infty}\cap\prod_nU_n=\bigcup_{i\gg0}\prod_{n\le i}U_n\times\prod_{n>i}\{0\}$ is open in our final topology.

Comment: @Thorgott You are right, I've edited the answer so that know $y$ does indeed belong to $U$ but not to $V$, and we get the desired result anyways. And, of course $U$ is open in the final topology because $U \in \tau'$ and we know $\tau' \subset \tau$, but what I wanted to point out is that the sets of this form are not a basis for $\tau$ and so the two topologies are distinct.

Comment: @JimingLe I don't really understand what you say, but $U$ is in $\tau'$ because of the definition of product topology, and it is in $\tau$ because of what Thorgott has shown in his answer or because we already know that $\tau' \subset \tau$.

Comment: @Eparoh What was your motivation to define $V$ as you did? Why $(-1,1)$?

Comment: It doesn't matter if it is $(-1,1)$ or any other interval (or distinct intervals, or even open sets in general) as long as they have zero as an element, so that its intersection with $R^\infty$ is non empty, and you know exactly some elements so you can define an element $y \in \mathbb{R}^\infty$ in the way I did.

Comment: @Eparoh but I don’t understand how did you know how to find a set that doesn’t belong to $\tau’$, but belongs to $\tau$? This would have been a problem for me if I would have seen this question in an exam. I wouldn’t be able to determine that $\tau’ \subsetneq \tau$ just by reading the question.

Comment: @JimingLe As I told you in the comments of your question, by the form of the $f_n$ I thought that every set of the form $U=\mathbb{R}^\infty \cap \prod_{n \in \mathbb{N}} U_n$ where each $U_n$ is open in $\mathbb{R}$, is open in your final topology. It is not difficult to prove this, and then you have that box topology is contained in this final topology. Box topology is not the same as product topology on $\mathbb{R}^\mathbb{N}$, so I just thought that maybe it wasn't also the same in this case on the subspace $\mathbb{R}^\infty$. Then I just picked a set of the form of $U$ and try.